# In Morningstar's premium screener's value pulldown, each value has two lines, one without "All" and one with. What is difference?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds

When building screen, in the "Build Your Screen" popup, under "4. Value | Benchmark" all the selection lines have "All" or not.

What does the "All" mean?

For example, one line has "U. S. Equity" and another has "All U. S. Equity"

What's the difference?

Comment: Please post a screenshot. User interfaces often change.